# What is the pragmatic way to immediately hide something after showing it in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, css-animations

In a game I am making in AngularJS, I want to display some text that should fade away immediately, indicating the amount of experience that a character is gaining. I have done this by adding an element to the DOM representing the experience text, that has an ngIf attached saying to show itself once the character kills the monster. However, now I need to immediately hide the text to trigger an ng-leave animation that fades out the text, and remove the text from the DOM, and I'm not sure how to go about doing this in a way that avoids mixing animation logic into my javascript.

Is there a design pattern for situations like this that lets me hide an element in the DOM right after it gets shown, without exposing details about the animation that should play to my JS code?

Comment: Check out this fiddle [CSS HIDE](http://jsfiddle.net/gryzzly/2VVBr/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is relatively straightforward. You can accomplish this with a directive and some css.

CSS:

```
myObj {opacity: 1; transition: all 2s}
vanish: {opacity: 0}
```

HTML:

```
<div my-object>Hello world.</div>
```

In the constructor for the `my-object` Angular directive:

```
$elem.addClass('vanish');
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems ideal for a custom directive that defines a "notification area" that listens (via $on) to events $broadcast from the $scope of a controller. The directive handles the creation of the message element in the DOM, as well as calling $animate.leave to remove it. You can see an example plunkr with the full code at

http://plnkr.co/edit/GMW1W26NNNQiGukDJp1A?p=preview

But the usage is, for a simplified case:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <button ng-click="clicked()">Click me!</button>
  <flash-notification></flash-notification>
</div>
```

And then in the controller you $broadcast the message:

```
$scope.$broadcast('flashNotification::message','Monster killed (or similar)');
```

How the directive works: it must listen to these events on its scope, like

```
scope.$on('flashNotification::message', function(e, message) { .... }
```

And then it can create the element, inject it into the *flash-notification* element, and then it can call $animate.leave to remove it after a delay and/or transition. See the above plunkr for the specifics of that part.

The nice thing about this pattern is that it's re-usable directive: you can put a *flash-notification* element in the template of any controller, so you don't have to do anything "globally" via services or $rootScope. Because of the use of $broadcast, only child scopes ever get the flashNotification message, and so if you have multiple uses of the flash-notificaiont directive the page, in controllers that are not in a parent/child relationship, each is completely isolated from the other.

One thing the plunkr code doesn't handle well, is several notification in quick succession. I wasn't sure what you wanted to happen, so it just stacks them up, and remove each after the same delay/transition.

Comment: i try to make preview for your answer but i have mistake please help me https://jsfiddle.net/saber13812002/wo1kefbq/1/

Answer (score 0):

I might be completely wrong about this but I believe the correct way to show and hide things in angular is to use the ng-hide/show directive. Assuming you wish to use this directive your element should look something like:

```
  <div class="ng-hide elementClass" ng-hide="scopeBoolean">the text</div>
```

Any time "scopeBoolean" is set to false this will SHOW the element. Any time it is set to "true" it will HIDE the element (ng-show reverses this logic). This actually adds and removes the ng-hide class automatically for you (I added this in the example manually so when the user loads the page you don't have it show up for a moment).

Now, the really cool thing with angular 1.2.2 and newer is that they now support animation, which you are probably going to want to use to make this a bit easier. Effectively, just modify the following css to get the transition you want to show or hide the element.

```
/* define baseline ng-hide */
.ng-hide { display: none; }

/* ng-hide transitions */
.elementClass.ng-hide-add, .elementClass.ng-hide-remove {
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear all;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s linear all;
    -o-transition: 0.5s linear all;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s linear all;
    transition: 0.5s linear all;
    display: block!important;
    opacity: 1;
}

.elementClass.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active, .elementClass.ng-hide-remove {
    opacity: 0;
}
.elementClass.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
     opacity: 1;
}
```

So, the FAQ for angular is correct: "Stop trying to use jQuery to modify the DOM in controllers. Really."

Enjoy!

Comment: if possible for you please make a preview in jsfiddle i try but not work https://jsfiddle.net/saber13812002/jbc0LsLz/ can you help me @drew-w